# Having trouble passing my user input in one method to the next method

Tags: parameters

Im new to java and I am in a CS1 class. I need some help understanding how i can get variables from one method to pass to another. I have done much research and talked to my professor but I seem to be getting the same errors everytime I attempt this concept. I always end up resorting to static variables and I understand the concept of scope buy I want to make sure to learn how to pass as this is going to be my career. Anyways i will provide an example of a section of code I wrote that i will need to turn in soon. I wont provide all of it, only the areas relating to the concept.

So a method for user input is used like so ...
Typing on a phone so assume there are curly braces and equals signs where needed.

```
public int acceptMonth(int month)

   System.out.println("Pick, 1 or 2 or 3") start
   month equals keyboard.nextInt

End
```

So i have my method that provides a case structure after the above method and prints "january has bla days" but only for those 3 numbers ( otherwise an invalid message is produced), how do I pass the user input value from acceptMonth() method to monthDecision() method the next method with the decision structure based on the user input? Is this necessary? Month is the only variable needed. If needed I will post the entire code once I have access to a computer. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Aaron

Comment: Made some typos including the location of the start. On a side note i would like to say that the most common error i get is the variable cannot be found error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not vary sure from from your question, but what ever I undrestood somthing like this can help:

```
public int acceptMonth(int month) {

     //paasing the month value to second method
     monthDecision(month);
}

private void monthDecision(int month) {
   switch(month)
    case 1:
        System.out.prrintln("janury has 31 day");
         break;
    case2:
        System.out.prrintln("Feb has 28 day");
        break;
    case 3:
         System.out.prrintln("March has 31 day");
         break;
    default:
          System.out.prrintln("Invalid mvalue");
}
```

Comment: @Marcin. Thanks for replying you constructed a replica of my code so good job! This should be good enough reference to find out what ive done wrong. Will post the code still for better analysis.